How to call a Perl script with couple of arguments with html tag from within a Python script using Subprocess/shell?
Within a python script I have a function which looks as below:
def NotifierFunc(Mail, Ticket_Num, Open_DtTime):
    cmd = "/home/path/MyPerlScript.pl --channel 'MyChannel' --userid 'itsme' --message 'Hello <at>"+Mail+"<at> : The ticket <a href='`echo 'http://snview/'"+Ticket_Num+">`echo "+Ticket_Num+"`</a> is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since "+Open_DtTime+" IST. Please close asap.' "
    print(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell= True, stout=subprocess.PIPE)


What it prints :
/home/path/MyPerlScript.pl --channel 'MyChannel' --userid 'itsme' --message 'Hello <at>Abc@xyz.com<at> : The ticket <a href='`echo 'http://snview/'INC23548>`echo INC23548`</a> is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since 4-APR-2024 12:30:40 IST. Please close asap.' 

This command does not get executed successfully in the shell primarily because the message (all that is passed after '--message' is within single quotes) or at least that is what is I think.
When I put that under double quotes python script throws syntax error.
When I put the whole cmd value in either single quote or doc string quote(''') and --message content in double quote that results in syntax error as well.
If I run below cmd  directly on the Linux command line (with the --message content within double quotes) it works fine:
> Mail="Abc@xyz.com"
> Ticket_Num="INC23548"
> Open_DtTime = "14-APR-2024 12:30:40"
> /home/path/MyPerlScript.pl --channel 'MyChannel' --userid 'itsme' --message "Hello <at>$Mail<at> : The ticket <a href='`echo 'http://snview/'$Ticket_Num >`echo $Ticket_Num`</a> is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since $Open_DtTime IST. Please close asap."

Now my question is how can I pass on this whole cmd value to subprocess so that the content of '--message' can be rendered correctly - or how can I put the '--message' content within double quotes and make it work.
Please note if I pass on the cmd as below - it works fine but it does not have the hyperlink for the ticket number. But I need the hyperlink.
cmd = "/home/path/MyPerlScript.pl --channel 'MyChannel' --userid 'itsme' --message 'Hello <at>"+Mail+"<at> : The ticket +Ticket_Num+" is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since "+Open_DtTime+" IST. Please close asap.' "

I have also tried putting the variables within {} and have tried various quote combinations. Nothing works so far.
I am using python 3.10

To clarify what the expected command should look like, can you show how you would call the Perl script from the command line? This could help us understand what you are trying to achieve from the Python script

maybe get string displayed by print(cmd) and try to run it directly in shell to see if it correct. As for me you have mistakes in HTML - they have ' which may have to be \'. You could also show this string in question. Maybe it will need also \\" or \\'

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

BTW: sometimes it is simpler to create only string with message and later put it in full string with cmd

@furas : Yes I have tried printing - it prints fine except the html part. I have also tried running it in linux command line - Just edited my question to add exactly what I ran from command line. Error simply says syntax error. Lemme try and put exactly what it shows when I print wthin python sccript

@HåkonHægland : added what I am running from Linux command line. Thanks

show this print in question (not in comments) - maybe it need only to add some \ or \

frankly, I don't understand why you use echo in Python code. Why not put values directly in string in Python.

show also result from print( cmd ). OR create minimal working code with example data - so we could simply copy and run it.

@furas : just added the result of the print(cmd)

first: you don't need echo in code. Second: because message is in  ' ' so you need \' inside this message href=\'.... \' - full message f" .... --message 'Hello <at>{Mail}<at> : The ticket <a href=\'http://snview/{Ticket_Num}\'>{Ticket_Num}</a> is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since {Open_DtTime} IST. Please close asap.'"


If you have no (unavoidable) need for a shell then don't go through a shell.  2) For that long "message" I'd prepare a string with it first, then use that to form a command.  (3) There's much too much going on in that 'message'.  Why backticks? Why echo?  So many quotes, even ' within ' (4) In newer Pythons can use run instead Popen


First: you don't need echo in Python because you put directly values, not shell variables.
Second: because message is in ' ' so inside this message you have to use \' to correctly format it.
But for shell it could be better to put link in " " inside message which is in ' ' - '..."..."...' - and because all string is in " " so inside string you need \"
like " '...\"...\"...' "
f" ... --message 'Hello <at>{Mail}<at> : The ticket <a href=\"http://snview/{Ticket_Num}\">{Ticket_Num}</a> is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since {Open_DtTime} IST. Please close asap.'"

Or you should put message in " " and inside message use ' ' -  - "...'...'..." - and again it need \" but in different place
like " \"...'...'...\" "
f" ... --message \"Hello <at>{Mail}<at> : The ticket <a href='http://snview/{Ticket_Num}'>{Ticket_Num}</a> is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since {Open_DtTime} IST. Please close asap.\""

Full code for test:
import subprocess

Mail="Abc@xyz.com"
Ticket_Num="INC23548"
Open_DtTime = "14-APR-2024 12:30:40"

cmd = f"./MyPerlScript.pl \
--channel 'MyChannel' \
--userid 'itsme' \
--message 'Hello <at>{Mail}<at> : The ticket <a href=\"http://snview/{Ticket_Num}\">{Ticket_Num}</a> is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since {Open_DtTime} IST. Please close asap.'"
print(cmd)

subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell= True)#, stout=subprocess.PIPE)


I agree using Echo  or back tick was never a good idea - I had first used format string - it dint work because of wrong escape characters which you have pointed out.. I googled and found it somewhere - so just was giving a try. What worked for me is not your first solution  (as the message was still coming within single quotes ) - But your second solution.    f" ... --message "Hello {Mail} : The ticket {Ticket_Num} is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since {Open_DtTime} IST. Please close asap.""
Thank you very much!

I was changing quotes in answer - so maybe you tried old version :)

No  no - what I meant is the option 1 below did not work for me : f" ... --message 'Hello {Mail} : The ticket <a href="http://snview/{Ticket_Num}">{Ticket_Num} is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since {Open_DtTime} IST. Please close asap.'"
Option 2 worked.

subprocess.Popen takes a list as first argument which makes it easier to handle and interpolate strings. Instead of having to escape some sequences because others contain quotes or double quotes, split them up like in the examples from the docs.
I created a test perl script that just prints each argument to run from python.
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(say);

say for @ARGV;

And executing it from python like so
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import sys


def NotifierFunc(Mail, Ticket_Num, Open_DtTime):
    cmd = [
        "./main.pl",
        "--channel",
        "MyChannel",
        "--userid",
        "itsme",
        "--message",
        f'Hello <at>{Mail}<at> : The ticket <a href="http://snview/{Ticket_Num}">{Ticket_Num}</a>'
        f" is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since {Open_DtTime} IST. Please close asap.",
    ]

    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False, stdout=sys.stdout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    NotifierFunc("Abc@xyz.com", "INC23548", "14-APR-2024 12:30:40")

Note that I set shell to False and changed stdout to test your example so I can see what it prints. I also made some other changes like removing backticks (which will spawn yet another subprocess in perl and call echo) and use f-strings instead.
This seems to print all the arguments as expected
› python main.py
--channel
MyChannel
--userid
itsme
--message
Hello <at>Abc@xyz.com<at> : The ticket <a href="http://snview/INC23548">INC23548</a> is not closed for more than 72 hours : Open since 14-APR-2024 12:30:40 IST. Please close asap.


Thank you for your reply. I tried this first as it looks really neat - however it came up with the error : "Use of uninitialised value  $channel in concatenation (.) or string at /home/path/MyPerlScript.pl "   Not sure what am I doing wrong - possibly something to with the way the perl script is written. If I print cmd within python then it simply prints the list.
